# AWS CDK Step Function EcsRunTask Use Input Variable For Task Definition

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions, ecs-taskdefinition

I am trying to convert a Step Function that I have in JSON to CDK (Typescript), but am not sure how to reference input variables from the previous step.

My existing Step Function Task:

```json
      "Start Task": {
        "Type": "Task",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
        "Parameters": {
          "LaunchType": "EC2",
          "Cluster": "my cluster arn",
          "TaskDefinition.$": "$.task"
        },
        "Next": "Task Success",
        "Catch": [
          {
            "ErrorEquals": [
              "States.ALL"
            ],
            "Next": "Task Failure"
          }
        ]
      }
```

How would I do `"TaskDefinition.$": "$.task"` in CDK? Or if I use CDK do I have to specify the task definition to run, instead of letting the input decide?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The CDK [aws_stepfunctions_tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks-readme.html) module has several ways to add an ECS task to a Step Function:

[EcsRunTask](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.EcsRunTask.html):  adds a ECS RunTask [Optimised Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ecs.html), but [does not accept an imported ARN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.EcsRunTask.html#taskdefinition) as the Task Definition. There is an [open feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/13003) that explains why not.  Supports `.sync` (`RUN_JOB`).

[CallAwsService](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.CallAwsService.html):  the CDK equivalent of Step Functions [AWS SDK Integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/supported-services-awssdk.html). You can pass `$.task` as the Task Definition ARN, but can't use the `.sync`pattern.

To use an input variable for the Task Definition AND wait for a response with `.sync`, you will need to get your hands dirty and subclass the [TaskStateBase](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/packages/@aws-cdk/aws-stepfunctions/lib/states/task-base.ts) construct.  You must handle [IAM permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/ecs-iam.html) yourself.  Here's a minimal implementation:

```js
export class RunEcsTaskAtPath extends sfn.TaskStateBase {
  protected readonly taskMetrics?: sfn.TaskMetricsConfig;
  protected readonly taskPolicies?: iam.PolicyStatement[];

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, private readonly props: TaskStateBaseProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
   
    this.taskPolicies = [
      // add the required policies:
      //    https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/ecs-iam.html
      // see also the `EcsRunTaskBase` `makePolicyStatements` method_
      //    https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-stepfunctions-tasks/lib/ecs/run-ecs-task-base.ts
    ];
  }

  protected _renderTask(): any {
    return sfn.FieldUtils.renderObject({
      Resource: 'arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync',
      Parameters: {
        LaunchType: 'EC2',
        Cluster: 'my cluster arn',
        TaskDefinition: sfn.JsonPath.stringAt('$.task'),
        // other config: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ecs.html
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Note the use of the CDK [JsonPath helpers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions.JsonPath.html). This is optional. You can also just hardcode the state machine syntax (`'TaskDefinition.$': '$.task'`).